# tkinter.menu.config doesn't work for python GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, menu

I tried to program a GUI in python using tkinter and python3.
First I import tkinter and filedialog module, then I create a window that contains text field.
The proble occur in the following line, the menu doesn't appear in the window:

```
MENU = tk.Menu(WIN)
WIN.config(menu=MENU)
fm = tk.Menu(MENU)
fm.add_command(label='Open...', command=do_open)
fm.add_command(label='Save', command=do_save)
fm.add_command(label='Save As...', command=do_saveas)
fm.add_separator()
fm.add_command(label='Quit', command=do_quit)
fm.add_cascade(label='File', menu=fm)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here try this.

```
        MENU = tk.Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=MENU)
        fm = tk.Menu(MENU)
        MENU.add_cascade(label='File', menu=fm)

        fm.add_command(label='Open...', command=do_open)
        fm.add_command(label='Save', command=do_save)
        fm.add_command(label='Save As...', command=do_saveas)
        fm.add_separator()
        fm.add_command(label='Quit', command=do_quit)
        fm.add_cascade(label='File', menu=fm)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is most detailed.

Answer (score 1):

You never add the `fm` menu to `MENU`.

Change this:

```
fm.add_cascade(label='File', menu=fm)
```

... to this:

```
MENU.add_cascade(label='File', menu=fm)
```